# Handler for Changing Texts in UIAlertView

Tags: xcode, uialertview, uitextfielddelegate

I need an event handler for the UITextFields inside UIAlertView. To be specific, when text in it is being changed. something like `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"text Entry");
}`

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: I am sorry.. No..I had to go in another route

Answer (score 0):

You should create a UITextField delegate class and set this for the textfields delegate property. Then implementing the method you mentioned in your question will fire once the textfield will be edited

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/

Good luck